# single page app django angular

Tags: django, angularjs

I have just started looking into using angularjs. I haven't done much front end development before and struggling to get my head around what handles what.

Would I be correct in saying that all I would use django for would be to create my models, REST api's and urls pointing to my api.

Would I no longer need to create views.py?

Comment: Yes, that would be the most likely approach. You create a backend REST API that communicates with your angular app via angular's `$http` service. Here's a good blog post on the topic: http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html

Comment: I made a tutorial for creating a todo app with django rest framework and angular. Scope the readme: https://github.com/jasonshark/angular-drf-todolist